How do I replace multiple substrings with no regard to the order it is done in C#?
How do i make multiple replacements in a string without the previous replacement affecting the first one? Is there a good way to do this in C#?
I want:
var startString = "abcd";
var replacement1 = "cd";
var replacement2 = "ef";
var result = startString.Replace("ab", replacement1 ).Replace("cd", replacement2);

To return:
"cdef"
Using the above approach gives me:
"efef"
replacement1 and replacement2 may contain any string. The search strings in the example "ab" and "cd" may not overlap.

Is it possible for the search strings to overlap? For example, "ab" -> "cd" and "bc" -> "ef", where "ab" and "bc" overlap in "abcd". If so, what should be the result?

In this trivial example you could simply reverse the order of the replacements. Is the real problem more complicated?

Clarified the search strings may not overlap. And since the replacements may be any string reversing the replace operations would not work.

In that case there is no easy way to automate this. You could do it by first replacing each replaceable string by its replacement order, and then replacing the order fields by the actual strings. So for example, in the sample above you replace "ab" with "{{1}}", and "cd" with "{{2}}". You then replace "{{1}}" with "cd", and "{{2}}" with "ef".

Maybe don't use replace? Just remove things you want to replace first. Store what and where you removed things and in the end insert the stored stuff at the stored position. You may need to fiddle a bit if the replacement string has a different length then the string it replaces.

You should probably use one of the overloads of Regex.Replace such as Regex.Replace(string, MatchEvaluator) which will allow to dynamically specify the replacement based on the matched substring.
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// list of values to replace with their replacements
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"ab", "cd"},
    {"cd", "ef"},
    {"ef", "ab"},
};

// Create a regular expression that will match any of the keys of the dictionary.
// Making sure to escape any characters that may interfere with the expression.
var escapedKeys = replacements.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x));
var regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", escapedKeys));

// Replace matches within the original string with their replacements
var result = regex.Replace("abcdef", (x) => replacements[x.Value]);

Console.WriteLine(result); // "cdefab"


Be careful to Regex.Escape the dictionary keys if building the pattern dynamically. It won't matter with these values, but it could with others.

You should sort replacements by their Lengths in descending order: we should try {"abcd", "x"} first and only then {"ab", "y"}, otherwise abcd will never be applied.

@DmitryBychenko That requires overlapping search strings, which is supposedly not possible.

@DmitryBychenko OP already stated that the search strings may not overlap, so there should not be any complications caused by the order in the regular expression.

You can do this with a recursive process, which works for any number of replacements:
string ReplaceMulti(string startString, IEnumerable<(string, string)> replacements)
{
    if (!replacements.Any())
    {
        return startString;
    }
            
    var (from, to) = replacements.First();

    var rest = replacements.Skip(1);

    return string.Join(
        to,
        startString
            .Split(new[] { from }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(s => ReplaceMulti(s, rest))
    );
}


// result: cdef
Console.WriteLine(ReplaceMulti("abcd", new[] { ("ab", "cd"), ("cd", "ef") }));

// result: cdefcdefgh
Console.WriteLine(ReplaceMulti("abcdabcdef", new[] { ("ab", "cd"), ("cd", "ef"), ("ef", "gh") }));

It recursively splits the string on each "from" value, performs the same replacement process on each piece from the split (minus the first from/to) pair, and then stitches the results back together with string.Join.

You can first get all indices for each "word" searched, then replace each match one by one from the highest to the lowest index.
    (string s, string r)[] map = [
        ("ab", " Charles Docduty,\n"),
        ("cd", " Elif Faijef,\n"),
        ("ef", " Gaby Hughes,\n"),
        ("gh", " Alex Baba,\n")];

    var source = "abcdefghefcdghefabcd";        
    var tmp = new StringBuilder(source);
    foreach (var (charPos, s, r) in map.SelectMany((sr, m) 
              => Indexes(source, sr.s), (sr, i) => (i, sr.s, sr.r)).OrderByDescending(t => t.i))
    {
        tmp.Replace(s, r, charPos, s.Length);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("replacement result   :\n{0}", tmp);      
    
    IEnumerable<int> Indexes(string v, string s)
    {
        int p = -s.Length;
        while((p = v.IndexOf(s, p+= s.Length)) > -1)
            yield return p;
    }

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lTU05N

The approach is correct however, you understood it differently. With your approach, the compiler will look for all 'ab' and replace it with 'cd' which will result in 'cdcd' and then it will look for all 'cd' and replace it with 'ef' which will result in 'efef'
The correct order here would be
var result = startString.Replace("cd", replacement2 ).Replace("ab", replacement1);


This was already dismissed by clarifications in the comments to the question which was subsequently updated.
